# How to create drug synergy plot?

Tags: python, drugs

I want to replicate the synergy drug response curve with the Python library given in the following paper.
Could you kindly advice on:

- Suitable graphics libraries for Python
- Code or pseudo code

Apologies because I don't currently have a test code.

I would really appreciate if anyone could guide me in this.
Thank you in advance.

Fig 1a

https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-022-04437-2/figures/1

[image]

Comment: The two major graphics packages in Python are matplotlib and seaborn. The very best graphics package (in my opinion - hence its a comment) is R's ggplot2. To do this in Python you usually use either a pandas Dataframe or Numpy. This example looks like curve fitting

Comment: for which one of the 2025 combinations ?

Comment: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-022-04437-2/figures/5 should help ?? To me its just a faith thing

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/synergy/  A python package to calculate, analyze, and visualize drug combination synergy and antagonism. Currently supports multiple models of synergy, including MuSyC, Bliss, Loewe, Combination Index, ZIP, Zimmer, BRAID, Schindler, and HSA.

Comment: This is a separate question.

Comment: @pippo1980 as per understanding between the delta IC50 and Emax of 108,259 combi_id's present in the file shared with figshare

Comment: Not sure there is one one way to obtain a Bliss curve (https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fphar.2017.00158/full) wasnt able to find the equation/bliss model they used but I did a superfast speed read of the article

Comment: Mmmmh Think I should start from scratch (Ic50 Ec50 single agent ).. then try tonunderstand synergy... this pic through me off https://els-jbs-prod-cdn.jbs.elsevierhealth.com/cms/attachment/43469fda-2391-474f-a97f-4a7307fa6f99/gr1.jpg

Comment: @pippo1980 same here :)

Comment: here found something in methods:  Conceptually, every point on the Bliss dose response curve is defined as the product between the anchor viability and the corresponding point on the library dose response curve. Shifts in potency (∆IC50) and in efficacy (∆Emax) were calculated as the difference between the observed combination response and expected Bliss (∆IC50 = Bliss IC50 − combination IC50, and ∆Emax = Bliss Emax − combination Emax). ∆IC50 is reported on a log2 scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you started. Complex editing in matplotlib isn't intuitive.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from numpy import linspace, sin
# you don't need math its just to get the value of pi for this data
import math 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


xaxis = linspace(1,1.75*math.pi,10)
drug2 = linspace(1,1.45*math.pi,10)

drug1 = sin(xaxis)
drug2b = sin(drug2)
plt.plot(xaxis, drug1, xaxis, drug2b)
plt.legend(['Drug 1', 'Drug 2'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

The authors look to have curve fitted and for that you would use `import scipy.optimize as opt`

Comment: shouldnt be drug1+drug2 ?

Comment: Better written as Expected and Observed but it is entirely hypothetical to demonstrate matplotlib.